# Is there any builtin way to add datatable in custom module admin panel?

Tags: magento2

I want to use datatable for custom module phtml in the admin panel. Should i use bootstrap datatable as mentioned in [this](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) link. 
Or, there is any standard builtin feature to add datatable in Magento 2 admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html), you can add a page to the admin panel and make a custom PHTML file with the datatable.

Comment: your mentioned link is only to add page in admin panel.

Comment: isnt, that wat you are asking to add?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento what you're describing is commonly known as an "Admin Grid". This is an admin table which lists the items from your database and provides common features like sort, filter, delete, update item, etc. This layout component already exists in the Magento "Framework" so it would be normal practice to use this rather than create something bespoke using DataTables. There is a good tutorial at MagePlaza for [how to create an admin grid in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html).